# Laravel - Não pega a coluna da tabela

Tags: php, html, laravel, mvc

Estou num dilema no `Laravel` que não consigo resolver, e já tentei muitas coisas e agora travei nisso aqui: O que quero é dar um `echo` de um valor da coluna da minha tabela em um `input` no `html`.

Código no `Controller`:

```
public function retorna_curso()
{
    $id_curso = Input::get('id_curso');
    $cursos = DB::table('cursos')->get();
    $select = DB::table('cursos')->where('id_curso', '=', $id_curso)->get();
    return view('editar.update_curso')
            ->with('select', $select)
            ->with('cursos', $cursos);
}
```

Código na `View`:

```
<form action="/updt_curso" method="post"> 
 <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <?php              
       if(isset($select))
       {
            echo' <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="edt_nome">Editar nome do curso:</label>
                <input type="text" 
                       class="form-control" 
                       name="input_nomeCurso" 
                       value="'.$select['nome'].'" 
                       id="nomeCurso">';                    
            echo'
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <input type="submit" 
                       value="Atualizar" 
                       class="form-control btn btn-primary">
            </div>';
        }                   
    ?>
 </div> 
</form>
```

Ele entra no `if`, mas dá uma exceção dizendo que a propriedade `nome` não existe no `array` `$select` que envio de volta para a pagina.

- O que eu poderia fazer para resolver esse problema?
- O que falta para funcionar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use apenas um `with` com o array que deseja enviar para a view:

```
...
return view('editar.update_curso')->with(['select' => $select, 'cursos' => $cursos]);
```

Lembre-se que `$select` é um array de objetos, em que cada linha é um objeto, terá de selecionar qual o indice (linha) que quer, que neste caso é a primeira pois o id suponho que seja unico na tabela, troque o seu if por:

```
if(isset($select[0])) { // verificar se há alguma linha retornada
```

E no value fica:

```
    ... value="' .$select[0]->nome. '" ...
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Nem acredito que era tão simples assim depois de tanta coisa que tentei kkkk. Obrigado Miguel!

Comment: De nada @Renan, ainda bem